# Showing that there are infinitely many integer solutions for the hyperbolic formula $|a^2 - 26 b^2| = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to show that the formula

$$ | a^2 - 26\cdot b^2| = 1$$

has infinitely many solutions $(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.

First I tried to solve the formula for one of the two variables, to get something like $a = ±\sqrt{±1 + 26 b^2}$ or $b = \sqrt{-\frac{±1 - a^2}{26}} $, but both doesn't look very promising, seeing as I would now need to prove that there are infinitely many integer solutions for $b$ (or $a$) so that the respective other one is also an integer.

I did, however, get some solutions. I could (by more or less trying out values) find out that $(5, 1), (51, 10)$ are two solutions. (And therefore also $(-5, 1)$ and so on.) So maybe there is a recursive way to get new values, based on the ones I already have, i.e. a formula $\phi(a, b)$ so that, when $(a, b)$ is an integer solution, $\phi(a, b)$ is aswell? (We would probably need an extra condition like that the components of $\phi(a, b)$ are strictly larger than $a, b$, so that we really get new solutions and not the ones we already had before.)

Seeing as I don't actually want to find a formula or so for the actual solutions, it would also be sufficient if there's a proof that there are infinitely many solutions that doesn't involve actually finding any of the solutions. But so far, I haven't had any luck with that.

(I wasn't entirely sure what tags to choose; the problem seemed analytical to me if other tags are seen as more suiting, please feel free to correct them.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(5a+26b)^2-26(a+5b)^2=-(a^2-26b^2)$. So you can use a solution to generate another larger solution. Eg starting with $(5,1)$, you get $(51,10)$.

Comment: @mathlove Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

$|a^2-26b^2|=1$ has infinitely many solutions if and only if $a^2-26b^2=1$ or $a^2-26b^2=-1$ has infinitely many solutions.

The latter are known as the [Pell equations (Wikipedia link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) and have been stuided thoroughly. The Wikipedia page has full explanations on how to find parametrizations. You might also want to look into the [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html) site.

Answer (score 3):

If $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{26}$, let $N(\alpha)=a^2 - 26b^2$. Then $N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$.

Now, by inspection, if $\theta = 5+\sqrt{26}$,then $N(5+\sqrt{26})=-1$.

Therefore, $|N(\theta^n)|=|N(\theta)^n|=1$ and so $\theta^n$ gives you an infinitude of solutions.

Note that $\theta^n=a_n + b_n \sqrt{26}$, with $a_n,b_n \in \mathbb Z$. In fact,
$$
\begin{array}%
a_{n+1} =& 5a_n+26b_n, && a_0 =& 1 \\
b_{n+1} =& a_n + 5b_n, && b_0 =& 0
\end{array}
$$

Comment: right. and Cayley-Hamilton for your two by two matrix gives separate linear recursions, one for your $a_n$ and one for $b_n$

Comment: which you may well have known, I'm just sayin'

Comment: @WillJagy, yes, good point!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you did not want. All of them.
$$ x_n^2 - 26 y_n^2 = (-1)^n, $$ with
$$ x_0 = 1, \; \; x_1 = 5, \; \; x_2 = 51, \; \; x_3 = 515, \; \; x_4 = 5201, \ldots $$
$$ y_0 = 0, \; \; y_1 = 1, \; \; y_2 = 10, \; \; y_3 = 101, \; \; y_4 = 1020, \ldots $$
with
$$ x_{n+2} = 10 x_{n+1} + x_n, $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 10 y_{n+1} + y_n. $$

To arrive full circle, the pair of recursions are simply saying that $x_n/y_n$ is a convergent for $\sqrt {26},$ and the "digits" for that continued fraction are
$$ \left[5; 10, 10, 10, 10, \ldots \right] $$

Alright, curious what happens in general. If we have positive $N$ such that negative Pell is solvable, and we take the **smallest** solution
$$ u^2 - N v^2 = -1  $$
with positive $u,v$ then we have $x_n - N y_n^2 = (-1)^n,$ where
$$ x_0 = 1, \; \; x_1 = u, \; \; x_2 = 2u^2 + 1, \; \; x_3 = 4 u^3 + 3u, \; \; x_4 =  8u^4 + 8u^2 + 1 ,\ldots $$
$$ y_0 = 0, \; \; y_1 = v, \; \; y_2 = 2uv, \; \; y_3 = 4 u^2 v + v, \; \; y_4 = 8 u^3 v + 4 u v, \ldots $$
and
$$ x_{n+2} = 2u x_{n+1} + x_n, $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 2u y_{n+1} + y_n. $$